# Why we can't declare any *Params Annotaion at Class(RCC) level, while declaring @Singleton at a same time in Jax-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

While making Root Resource Class as a `@Singleton` and declaring `@QueryParam` Annotation at same time at a Class level,

```
@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class MyResource{

    @QueryParam("q1") String q1;

    @Path("/test")
    public Response getQueryParam(){

        return Response.entity(q1).build;   
    }
}
```

I am getting below exception with 500 Error code at Request time, **Please help me If anyone have knowledge about cause for this exception.**

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-documentation/2.0/jersey-documentation-2.0-user-guide.pdf) in `Example 3.24`

> will cause validation failure during application initialization as
>   singleton resources cannot inject request specific parameters. The
>   same example would fail if the query parameter would be injected into
>   constructor parameter of such a singleton. In other words, if you wish
>   one resource instance to server more requests (in the same time) it
>   cannot be bound to a specific request parameter.

Since `QueryParam` is **request-specific** you can't use it with `@Singleton`

**@Context to the rescue!**

The good knews is that you can inject other type of objects which can be injected using the `@Context` annotation, proxy objects are used for these; thus allowing to be used in singletons:

```
@Context
private UriInfo urinfo;

private String queryparam;

@GET
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response bla(){

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = urinfo.getQueryParameters(true);

    queryparam = params.containsKey("yourparam") ? 
                            params.get("yourparam").get(0) 
                            : "not in request";

    return Response.ok(queryparam).build();
}
```